# Start nodejs server on centos

Tags: 7

I install Nodejs integration module in drupal7, then install Nodejs package on CentOS 6.4; In instruction [nodejs integration](https://www.drupal.org/node/1713530) i see: 
'In your terminal window, start the node server using the following command:'

```
node server.js
```

but in module directory, i haven't file "server.js"

can anyone help?

Comment: server.js should be on your server in /usr/bin/.... etc. You need to first install nodeJS on your server. For ubuntu you use `sudo apt-get install nodejs` not sure if for CentOS if it's the same.

Comment: Here is a video tutorial installing it on Ubuntu [Installation of Node.js integration module for Drupal 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1sxDaH3Z-U)  and for [Drupal 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znr0aFOlDnI). Even though, you are using CentOS the video tutorial will give you a good idea how to do it.

Comment: i'm already install nideJS, there are no server.js in /usr/bin/

Comment: you need to install it first, see my edited 1st comment.

Comment: i watch the video, install nodeJs, but can't run!!!

Comment: you get an error?

Comment: i can't find file "server.js", and i can't run it )

Comment: sorry, it's been a while since I've setup nodejs, you're right the server.js file should be in the modules folder.

Comment: maybe it gets created/generated when you first try to run `node server.js` or maybe when you install the npm package.

Comment: Shouldn't you use only "node" http://blog.gvm-it.eu/post/20404719601/getting-started-with-nodejs-on-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server.js file has indeed been removed from the package. The solution is in the readme:

> ## Setup
>
> 1. Install drupal-node.js packge with npm:
>
>    npm install drupal-node.js
>
> Make sure to do this outside of your Drupal modules directory, else
>   Drupal may try to process folders containing Node.js module
>   information and fail. Follow the install instructions in the
>   drupal-node.js NPM package. You will need to provide the hostname and
>   port of your Drupal site to the Node.js process, and ensure that the
>   service token matches between Drupal and Node.js.

I suppose they separated the server from the Drupal module to allow more frequent updates.
The npm package contains a settings file and `app.js`, which includes `server.js`.