# Nodejs integration for Chatroom

Tags: 7, nodejs

I am following the [Nodejs integration documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1713530) to set up [Chatroom](https://www.drupal.org/project/chatroom), but am a little confused.

In step 2, do we cd to the folder of nodejs installation, or the drupal nodejs module?

Also, what is the server.js file?

Comment: For Server.js file, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192573/start-nodejs-server-on-centos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [Neograph734](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/9921/neograph734) in the [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192573/start-nodejs-server-on-centos), the current Node.js integration documentation is outdated, and the working instructions for setting up the node.js server with Drupal is in the Node.js Integration readme.txt file.

First, `npm install drupal-node.js`, and then run `node app.js` in the drupal-node.js folder, where app.js replaces the old server.js in the current Node.js Integration documentattion.

Answer (score 1):

Updated the documentation page.

In step 2, we need to move in to `nodejs` module folder inside your drupal's **sites** directory. Install the dependencies using package manager(npm). Most probably the `nodejs` module is installed at `sites/all/modules/nodejs`.

Also don't get confused by these notation (`path/to/your/nodejs/module/directory`). It used to say that it exist in some directory.

`server.js` holds the code related to your **express** application from configuring your app to starting your app. Express will be installed in your `node_modules` folder when you install the dependencies. `node_modules` will be created in you `nodejs` module(drupal site).

`node server.js` starts the **express** application from the location where **server.js** file is present.

Also you can follow the tutorial links provided by [No Sssweat](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/27710/no-sssweat).

Comment: Thanks for this , but it seems there have been a few changes to the drupal-node directory structure, as pointed out in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192573/start-nodejs-server-on-centos.

Answer (score 0):

> In step 2, do we cd to the folder of nodejs installation, or **the
>   drupal nodejs module**?

In **the drupal nodejs module** (`cd /sites/all/modules/nodejs` then `node server.js`)

Here is an [installation video tutorial for Drupal 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1sxDaH3Z-U)

Here is an [installation video tutorial for Drupal 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znr0aFOlDnI)